# Programmatic interface to the GNAT compiler?

Tags: plugins, ada, dynamic-loading

Is there a supported way to have an Ada program call out to GNAT to compile a source file, and then load the result dynamically?

(By 'supported' I mean: better than shelling out to gnatmake.)

Background: I have a program whose configuration files contain code. Right now I have an LLVM-based library, written in C++, which I have C bindings to and call out to from Ada, which handles this: it loads the configuration files, JIT compiles them into (commendably fast) machine code, and then I call out to them from Ada.

This is horrible.

It would be far cleaner to simply write the configuration in Ada, and compile and link it against the program. But I don't want to force the end user to have to set up a build system. What I'd like is for the end user to just point my program at the configuration files, and then have the program compile and dynamically load them invisibly, without the user needing to care.

This sounds like exactly the sort of thing that someone's already done. Have they? (I only care about Unixoids like Linux, if that helps.)

Comment: Why do you want to bypass gnatmake here ? Its purpose is exactly to build the Ada file, and you can of course easily spawn the executable if the compilation finishes successfully. One of the drawbacks might be the need to pass the appropriate -I switches to find your dependencies, but you would need that whatever method you use to compile. What do the config files contain, perhaps you could use OpenToken or some parser generator to parse them and then interpret them ? You might not need the full power of Ada here.

Comment: Shelling out the compiler is fiddly and very brittle --- I've done it before in other languages and it's never satisfactory. (What happens if the user upgrades their compiler and it gets picked up by the path? What happens if they set an environment variable which causes an ABI change in compiled code thus making it incompatible with my executable? etc etc). Having a turnkey library that directly invokes the compiler makes all these problems go away. Ideally I'd like a turnkey library which will allow me to load Ada packages from source at runtime, but I don't think I'll get one.

Comment: There was a mix between compiler (gnat or gcc) and the builder (gnatmake) which is in charge of spawning one or more compiler instances. That's why I was confused when you said you did not want to use gnatmake. So again my suggestion would be to forget the use of a fully programming language for a configuration file. Instead, use a simpler passive description, which you can preprocess/precompile into bytecode if speed of parsing is a concern. OpenToken provides a nice way to implement such parsers quite easily. GNATCOLL.JSON could also be of use, as well as GNATCOLL.Config

Comment: No, it's got to turn into real machine code - it's numerical computation formulae. That's why my current approach is using LLVM. An interpreted file won't cut it.